# gridview replace string from a boundfield

Tags: string, gridview, replace

I have a SPGridView that displays items from a list (using spboundfield).

The multi-lookup fileds in my SPGridview the filter values of a lookupfield appear in this format:

{id};#{Value}

How do I replace the id;# from the field?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I solved this issue. (NOTE i had to put a dot before asp and itemtemplate for this post. remove those dots) 

asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Campaign Members">
 ItemTemplate> 
%# RemoveCharacters(Eval("CampaignMembers").ToString())%>
 /ItemTemplate> 
/asp:TemplateField>

// Make sure declare using System.Text.RegularExpression;
 protected string RemoveCharacters(object String) 
{
 string s1 = String.ToString(); 
string newString = Regex.Replace(s1, @"#[\d-];", string.Empty); 
newString = Regex.Replace(newString, "#", " "); 
return newString.ToString();
 }